# Make two background images responsive alongside divs with CSS

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries, background-image

I am struggling with getting 2 background images to shrink in sync with each other, so my seat plan will work on mobile/tablets.

I have tried background cover, contain, 100% and setting other div values to 100% but no joy with keeping those seats positioned in place.

So not only does the background image need to shrink for the seatplan below 650px, but also the seat images do too - they need to maintain their position on the seat plan. The containing divs are currently set at 15px to display the seat images.

Here is the original static width code I am working with
https://jsfiddle.net/kjyopdL8/

**The seat sizes should be 15px in size until the seatplan goes below 650px, then the seats images shrink in sync with the main seatplan image whilst remaining in the same position and proportion**

```css
#theatre {
  width: 650px;
  float: left;
  padding-right: 5px;
  margin: 25px 15px 0 10px;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#bmessage {
  padding: 1px 3px;
  height: 20px;
  font-size: 14px;
  background: #ddf;
  color: #080;
  font-weight: bold;
}
#seats:before {
  content: url('http://i.imgur.com/qn56yss.gif');
}

#seats {
  margin: 10px 0;
  padding: 10px 0;
  position: relative;
}

#seats div {
  position: absolute;
  width:15px;
  height:15px;
}

#seats .s1.std.grey {
  background: url('https://s3.postimg.org/g9dq32nqr/1_1_2.png') no-repeat center top;
}
```

```html
<div id="theatre">
  <div class="container">
    <div id="bmessage">Select the seats that you need.</div>
    <div id="seats">
      <div class="s1 std grey" si="0" title="A16" style="top:16%; left:8.5%;"></div>       
      <div class="s1 std grey" si="1" title="A15" style="top:16%; left:12%;"></div>
      <div class="s1 std grey" si="2" title="A14" style="top:16%; left:15.5%;"></div>       
      <div class="s1 std grey" si="3" title="A13" style="top:16%; left:19%;"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

theres a lot of error on your css. dont give fix width on your container if you want it to be responsive. ive edited your fiddle and came up with this: https://jsfiddle.net/kjyopdL8/4/

```
#seats:before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    padding: 50%;
}

#seats {
    margin: 10px 0;
    padding: 10px 0;
    position: relative;
    background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/qn56yss.gif);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

take a look at the pseudo selector before. it did the trick!

Comment: This is looking good-thankyou, whats the purpose of the 50% :"before" padding?

Comment: no css on "theatre" div and shoudn't the seat sizes shrink? (they remain at 15px)

Comment: Basically, it gives the whole container 50% padding on top right bottom and left. Whatever the window width is, it will get the 50% of it thats why it shrinks. Ive updated the fiddle. I use % instead of px with the seat div. it should now resize accordingly.

Comment: The seat sizes should be 15px in size until the seatplan goes below 650px (see the original #theatre div), then shrink in sync with the seatplan. its lookign good but atm the seat images are too small.

Answer (score 4):

Ethan Marcotte has written extensively on responsive background images.
You can read lots on his blog or [here.](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/07/simple-responsive-images-with-css-background-images/#scaling-images-in-the-browser).

You basically want to set the following properties to you background image:

1. Set the display property of the #image element to inline-block. Without this property, CSS will display the `<span>` element as inline and we won’t be able to give it a width or (in a minute) a height.
2. Set the width of that element to 100% so that our image fills the containing `<div>`.
3. Set the font-size and line-height properties to 0 so that any contents within the span don’t factor into its size.
4. Set the vertical-align property to middle to vertically center the image element in the containing `<div>`.
   Set the background-size property to 100% so our image fills the image element.
5. Set the background-position property to 50% 50% to align the background image within the image element.
6. Set the background-repeat property to no-repeat to prevent the browser from tiling the image horizontally or vertically.

If you take this approach for your overlaid and the image under and they are both the same size then you should have no issues with alignment.

Media queries will then help you with handling different screen sizes.

Comment: There is an awful lot in there, could you have a go with the JSFiddle? I have added those properties to the background url selectors with no joy.  https://jsfiddle.net/f3nr70yh/